# GoTo function in cshtml.cs to go to a cshtml page

Tags: razor

I want to write a login function in cshtml.cs that sends the user to an other cshtml page. 
If the userdata were correct the function sends the user to the next page.

```
    public void OnPost()
    {

        if (LoginCheck())
        {
            Message = "success";
            //Login was a success. Go to the next page
        }
        else
        {
            Message = "failure";
            //Login was a failure. Noting happens. exept the message
        }

    }
```

Comment: `OnPost` should return `IActionResult` so you can `return Redirect` or `return RedirectToAction` or `return LocalRedirect`

Comment: Why you tagged `razor`, what is `razor` here?

Comment: when i want to tag cshtml stackoverflow only give me razor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works. Maybe doesn´t look that great, but it works ;)

```
    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {

        if (LoginCheck())
        {
            Message = "success";
            //Login was a success. Go to the next page
            return Redirect("/FileIwantTo");
        }
        else
        {
            Message = "failure";
            //Login was a failure. Noting happens. exept the message
            return Redirect("/FileI´mStaying");
        }

    }
```